# Renting a car in france with a German license that is less than 1yr old

Tags: france, car-rentals, automobiles, driving-licenses, rental

I want to rent a car from Toulouse in 2 weeks but I couldn't find any rental companies that rent a car to someone with a license < 1yr old.

Is it a law in France? If not, are there any companies offering cars to people with a license that is less than 1yr old? I'm older than 25.

Comment: How would that even come up?  The issue date is when the actual card was issued, not when you got your first Driver License.

Comment: Hi Johns, I got my license a few months ago.

Comment: I get that, but there's nothing on the card itself that indicates that.  Unless the agency is asking you separately "How long have you been driving?"  In which case, they may have an internal policy that says you have to have been driving >1 year to rent one of their cars.

Comment: Ah, but my German license has a date, Ausstellungsdatum :/

Comment: I'm going to stop here as a European Driver License may have a special endorsement indicating the first issue date.  The date on the front though is the physical card issue date, not when you first got a Driver License.

Comment: Yea, in a German license there is both date of issue for the card and the date when the license was made.

Comment: There is no law that I am aware of, but also there is no car rental that will let you drive. The problem seems to be that the rental agencies couldn't get insurance for their cars if they wanted to rent out to newbies.

Comment: Don't think it's a legal issue, but rather a matter of insurance. In many cases there's a minimum of 3 years (sometimes more), and some companies let you pay extra to lower the age, but I don't think you could go down to less than a year. You can rent cars that don't require a license, though (less than 50cm3 motor).

Comment: @Johns-305 Yes, EU driver licenses include the first issuing date in column 10 on the back.

Comment: @pnuts Interesting. I was pretty sure this was required by Directive 2006/126/EC (also present in the first plastic card Directive, 96/47/EC) but there may be exceptions I'm not aware of. It's not something I'm well informed in to be honest.

Comment: It will be barely possible for you to rent a car in Germany although there is no law which would forbid that.

Comment: @Johns-305 The date you passed the exam is on all EU driver's license I have seen. Until recently, many (including French and German licenses) did not have an issue date at all (because they were valid for life). From a European perspective, that's not "special" in any way, it's the lack of initial issue date on US license that seems odd.

Comment: @neo The first directive did not cancel older licenses, the last one has a transition period that reaches until 2033 (IIRC). Presumably, pnuts' license was issued under older rules but those can still be valid for many years to come.

Comment: @Relaxed Ah yes thanks, I was thinking of the ID-card-style EU licenses. The older national ones look different of course.

Comment: @Alex.S I can rent a car in Germany via Sixt without any problems.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, it is not a legal, but an insurance issue. It is possible, but not cheap. I did this recently, as a 22 year old driver with a 3 months old license, but I ended up paying quadruple the normal rental price. Consider how much it is worth for you, both in money and in risk.

You are most likely to succeed by calling small, local rental agencies. This is how I did it. They do not always have a policy in place against this, in contrary to big companies like Hertz and Avis.

You can also try taking your chances and turning up at a rental company. You will have to decide if you want to prepay or not. Prepaying is cheaper and may help you get a car, but I have no idea what would happen if they then refuse you because you haven't held your license for long enough.

Good luck and please share what happened.

Comment: A friend can not get a car when he tries to rent in by himself but has no problems when the company rents one for him. Being a young male makes many companies wonder if you can pay for damages, being older helps in assuring you can.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me through which rental company he rented? I will also rent via my company.

Comment: Hi @J. Constantine Can you please tell me through which rental company you rented? Money is not a problem and I don't think I'm a reckless driver, I've been driving a car for more than 10years but had to get an EU license after I moved to Germany.

Comment: @mgr Would you be eligible to rent the car under your non-German license? Is it still valid?

Comment: Hi Andrew, unfortunately I only have a copy of my non German license :(

Comment: It was a small business with just 5 cars, don't remember the name. Something rent-a-car.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a legal issue, but rather a matter of insurance (and its cost).

In most cases, a requirement on both age (21 or 25 years old) and time holding a driver's license (3 or 5 years) is typical, however this varies from network to network and even from branch to branch (especially in the case of franchises, they may set their own rules).

Rent-a-Car for instance has a standard 3 or 5 years minimum, but you can pay extra to reduce that by 2 years, so that still leaves you with a 1 year minimum.

Ada however may allow you to drive a car with just days on your license:
http://www.ada.fr/jeunes/index.html

Following the link on that page results (at least in the location I selected) in many cars (mostly cheaper models) available with no requirement on how long you've held your licence.

Comment: Hi, do you happen to know if they are good/bad? Thanks a lot for the link!